# Zooreg frequency warning

Tags: r, zoo

Suppose I have the following set of data:

```
date <- structure(c(1986, 1986.08333333333, 1986.16666666667), class = "yearmon")

return <- structure(c(0.000827577426231287, 0.00386371801344005, 0.00382634819565989
), .Dim = 3L, .Dimnames = list(c("1986-01", "1986-02", "1986-03"
)))
```

I used the following to transform the return `array` into a `zoo/zooreg` object:

`zooreg(return, order.by = date)`

It provides the correct output with a warning:

```
 Jan 1986     Feb 1986     Mar 1986 
0.0008275774 0.0038637180 0.0038263482
```

> Warning message:
>   In zoo(data, order.by, frequency) :
>     “order.by” and “frequency” do not match: “frequency” ignored

The series is strictly regular and the `order.by` and `frequency` should match but I still couldn't figure out why there is a warning.

Comment: The `years` are not integer. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @Christoph no it is not, it results from averaging daily figures of stock retunrs into monthly values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation (`?yearmon`):

> The "yearmon" class is used to represent monthly data. Internally it holds the data as year plus 0 for January, 1/12 for February, 2/12 for March and so on in order that its internal representation is the same as ts class with frequency = 12.

Calling:

```
zooreg(return, order.by = date)
```

is equivalent to calling

```
zoo(return, order.by = date, frequency = 1)
```

According to the documentation to `zoo` under `Arguments::frequency` :

> If specified, it is checked whether order.by and frequency comply.

Hence the warning. To get rid of the warning, use

```
z <- zooreg(return, order.by = date, frequency = 12)
```

or

```
z <- zoo(return, order.by = date, frequency = 12)
```

Both of these will return an object of class `zooreg`:

```
str(z)
‘zooreg’ series from Jan 1986 to Mar 1986
  Data: Named num [1:3] 0.000828 0.003864 0.003826
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "1986-01" "1986-02" "1986-03"
  Index: Class 'yearmon'  num [1:3] 1986 1986 1986
  Frequency: 12
```

which according to the documentation (`?zoo`),

> This is a subclass of "zoo" which relies on having a "zoo" series with an additional "frequency" attribute (which has to comply with the index of that series)

I believe this is what you want.

Note that calling with mismatched "order.by" and "frequency" using

```
z <- zooreg(return, order.by = date)
```

you get only a `zoo` object:

```
str(z)
‘zoo’ series from Jan 1986 to Mar 1986
  Data: Named num [1:3] 0.000828 0.003864 0.003826
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "1986-01" "1986-02" "1986-03"
  Index: Class 'yearmon'  num [1:3] 1986 1986 1986
```